# How to custom the image of MKAnnotation pin

Tags: swift, uikit, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am trying to change the image that is inside the `MKAnnotation` without removing the rounded shape.

Here I create a custom class of `MKAnnotation`:

```
class MapPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let title: String?
    let locationName: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    init(title: String, locationName: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.locationName = locationName
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

Here I create a MapPin and I add it to the mapView

```
func setPinUsingMKAnnotation() {
   let pin1 = MapPin(title: "Here", locationName: "Device Location", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 21.283921, longitude: -157.831661))
   let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: pin1.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 800, longitudinalMeters: 800)
   mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
   mapView.addAnnotations([pin1])
}
```

The first image is what I created, the second image is what I would like it to be.

[image]

I even implemented `MKMapViewDelegate`:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var annotationView = MKAnnotationView()
    annotationView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart")
    return annotationView
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

The rounded shape disappears.

I saw many tutorials about how to custom a pin, but they only explained how to put an image instead of the pin (like the hearth image above). I would like to know how to change the image (and color) of the pin and keep the rounded shape (see the blue pin image above).

Any hints? Thanks

Comment: FWIW, I might suggest using `MKPointAnnotation` rather than building your own `MKAnnotation`. Or, if you definitely need some additional properties, then fine, subclass `MKPointAnnotation` rather than starting from scratch. There's no point in reinventing the wheel (plus `MKPointAnnotation` makes these `title` and `coordinate` properties `dynamic`, which is useful).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want that rounded border, you can render it yourself, or easier, subclass `MKMarkerAnnotationView` rather than `MKAnnotationView`:

```
class CustomAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        didSet { configure(for: annotation) }
    }

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        glyphImage = ...
        markerTintColor = ...
            
        configure(for: annotation)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configure(for annotation: MKAnnotation?) {
        displayPriority = .required

        // if doing clustering, also add
        // clusteringIdentifier = ...
    }
}
```

That way, not only do you get the circular border, but you get all of the marker annotation view behaviors (shows the `title` of the annotation view below the marker, if you select on the marker annotation view, it becomes larger, etc.). There’s a lot of marker annotation view behaviors that you probably don’t want to have to write from scratch if you don’t have to. By subclassing `MKMarkerAnnotationView` instead of the vanilla `MKAnnotationView`, you get all those behaviors for free.

For example, you could:

```
class CustomAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    static let glyphImage: UIImage = {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect).image { _ in
            let radius: CGFloat = 11
            let offset: CGFloat = 7
            let insetY: CGFloat = 5
            let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY - radius - insetY)
            let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY + insetY), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - radius, y: center.y - offset))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + radius, y: center.y), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + radius, y: center.y - offset))
            path.close()
            UIColor.white.setFill()
            path.fill()
        }
    }()

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        didSet { configure(for: annotation) }
    }

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        glyphImage = Self.glyphImage
        markerTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.005868499167, green: 0.5166643262, blue: 0.9889912009, alpha: 1)

        configure(for: annotation)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configure(for annotation: MKAnnotation?) {
        displayPriority = .required

        // if doing clustering, also add
        // clusteringIdentifier = ...
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Obviously, when you set `glyphImage`, set it to whatever image you want. The old SF Symbols doesn't have that “drop” image (though iOS 14 has `drop.fill`). But supply whatever 40 × 40 pt image view you want. I'm rendering it myself, but you can use whatever appropriately sized image from your asset catalog (or from the system symbols) that you want.

---

As an aside, since iOS 11, you wouldn't generally wouldn't implement `mapView(_:viewFor:)` at all, unless absolutely necessary (which it isn't in this case). For example, you can get rid of your `viewFor` method and just register your custom annotation view in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.register(CustomAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the image dynamically to show different icons on the map? I have subclassed MKPointAnnotation to add a parameter telling me which kind of entry this is and depending on that I want to show a different icon, but I didn't find a way to make this solution dynamic as annotation and reuseIdentifier are nil when setting the image.

Comment: Yeah, you just move the setting of `glyphImage` into the `configure` method. Personally, I give my annotation (a `MKPointAnnotation` subclass) a custom property and check that.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. But I have some questions as well.

I want this annotation to look like points of interest that apple serves by default, i.e - smaller (lets say 24 by 24) and the title adjacent to it. What is the best way to do this?

Subclassing MKAnnotationView would open a huge can of worms so wondering what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: I’m not understanding the question: Why not just subclass `MKMarkerAnnotationView`, like shown above, and change the `glyphImage` accordingly? That lets you change the glyph and color and give you all the other behaviors for free. If you are looking for something more fundamentally different, then you’re looking at `MKAnnotationView` and re-implement the desired behaviors, and all the work that entails.